# Write data to cassandra using python parser

Tags: python-3.x, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-python-driver, datastax-python-driver

I have a user defined python library which parses the data from a file and returns key value pairs. Now how do I use this library to insert data into Cassandra column family? I’m using python Cassandra driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Datastax Driver Documentation?](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html#executing-queries)

Most specifically:

- Executing Queries
- Passing Parameters to CQL Queries

Generate a [PreparedStatement](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html#id2) for the insertion query and iterate over a list/tuple/generator with the key value pairs from your parsed file data.